# Set different ListView row heights

Tags: c#, listview, imagelist

I want to have a ListView with different row heights. This code for example makes every row 50 px high (img = ImageList and list = ListView):

```
img.ImageSize = new Size(1, 50);
list.SmallImageList = img;
```

But I want the first row to be 60 px, the next to be 100 px, and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: no. all items will have the same height. You may want to use a DataGridView instead.

Comment: No, it must be a ListView. I'm just gonna have to live without that then.